# CSS+HTML and IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

Now windows8 and IE10 is out as developer preview I have a question. What does IE10 don't support what IE9/8 does and what does it now support! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to read the [IE10 developer guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673549.aspx) and in particular its [CSS section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673536.aspx).
Or you could simply subscribe to the [IE blog feed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/rss.aspx).